# Is this the general solution to $m\mid n^2+n, n\mid m^2+m$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, divisibility

Is this the general solution to
$m\mid n^2+n, n\mid m^2+m$?

I saw this problem
in this Michael Penn video:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0J1ByEhwHRU

Here is my solution
(which is very different
than the solution
in the video):

Let
$uv=c^2+1$.
Then
$m=c(u+c), n=c(v+c)
$.

My question:

Are these the general solutions?

Note:
all variables are positive integers.

Verification:

$\begin{array}\\
m^2+m
&=m(m+1)\\
&=c(u+c)(c(u+c)+1)\\
&=c(u+c)(cu+c^2+1)\\
&=c(u+c)(cu+uv)\\
&=cu(u+c)(c+v)\\
&=nu(u+c)\\
n^2+n
&=n(n+1)\\
&=c(v+c)(c(v+c)+1)\\
&=c(v+c)(cv+c^2+1)\\
&=c(v+c)(cv+uv)\\
&=cv(v+c)(c+u)\\
&=mv(v+c)\\
\end{array}
$

Comment: If true, then $\gcd(m,n)=c\gcd(u+c,v+c).$ But  $$(u+c)v-(v+c)c=c^2+1+cv-cv-c^2=1,$$  so if your answer is correct, then given any solution, $m,n$ you must have $c=\gcd(m,n)$ Not sure where to go from there.

Comment: FYI, with [Approach0 search](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=OR%20content%3A%24m%5Cmid%20n%5E2%2Bn%24%2C%20OR%20content%3A%24n%5Cmid%20m%5E2%2Bm%24&p=1), [Post #$390$](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c4h319781p1879019) of the AoPS thread [ALGEBRA 2 Marathon!](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c4h319781p1718149) has Problem $308$ "A pair of integers $(m,n)$ is called good if $m\mid n^2+n$ and $n\mid m^2+n$. Given $2$ positive integers $a,b\gt 1$ which are relatively prime, prove that there exists a good pair $(m,n)$ with $a\mid m$ and $b\mid n$, but $a\nmid n$ and $b\nmid m$."

Comment: Note that, in my comment above, the $n\mid m^2+\color{red}{n}$ should be $n\mid m^2+m$ instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In [Thomas Andrews' answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4724981), using $c=\gcd(m,n)$ so $m=cm_0$ and $n=cn_0$ with $\gcd(m_0,n_0)=1$, there's the result, for $m_0\neq n_0$, of

$$m_0n_0\mid (m_0+n_0)c+1 \tag{1}\label{eq1A}$$

Also, since $m_0$ and $n_0$ are coprime, then $m_0=n_0$ means they're both $1$, so \eqref{eq1A} holds in that case as well. This equation shows that, for some integer $k \ge 1$, we have

$$\begin{equation}\begin{aligned}
(m_0+n_0)c+1 & = km_{0}n_{0} \\
kcm_0 + kcn_0 + k & = k^{2}m_{0}n_{0} \\
c^2 + k & = k^{2}m_{0}n_{0} - kcm_0 - kcn_0 + c^2 \\
c^2 + k & = (km_0 - c)(kn_0 - c)
\end{aligned}\end{equation}\tag{2}\label{eq2A}$$

Your result is a special case with $k = 1$. A more general solution is for any $k \ge 1$ where

$$uv = c^2 + k \tag{3}\label{eq3A}$$

so using $u = km_0-c$ and $v=kn_0-c$ in \eqref{eq2A}, we require $k \mid u+c$ and $k \mid v+c$. Then

$$m = \frac{c(u+c)}{k}, \; n = \frac{c(v+c)}{k} \tag{4}\label{eq4A}$$

is a solution. Similar to what you did, the verification is

$$\begin{equation}\begin{aligned}
m^2 + m & = m(m + 1) \\
& = \left(\frac{c(u+c)}{k}\right)\left(\frac{c(u+c)}{k}+1\right) \\
& = \frac{c(u+c)(c(u+c)+k)}{k^2} \\
& = \frac{c(u+c)(cu+c^2+k)}{k^2} \\
& = \frac{c(u+c)(cu+uv)}{k^2} \\
& = \frac{uc(u+c)(c+v)}{k^2} \\
& = \left(\frac{c(c+v)}{k}\right)\left(\frac{u(u+c)}{k}\right) \\
& = n\left(\frac{u(u+c)}{k}\right)
\end{aligned}\end{equation}\tag{5}\label{eq5A}$$

Since $k\mid u+c$, then $\frac{u(u+c)}{k}$ is an integer. We can also similarly verify that $n^2+n = m\left(\frac{v(v+c)}{k}\right)$.

---

As indicated in [Thomas Andrews' comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4724973/is-this-the-general-solution-to-m-mid-n2n-n-mid-m2m#comment10012908_4725015), with $k = 2$, then for every odd $c$, since $c^2 + k$ is odd, then all factors $u$ and $v$ are as well, so $k$ always divides $u+c$ and $v+c$. Also, this produces results not obtainable using $k=1$, with the first such one being $(c,k,u,v)=(1,2,3,1)$ giving $(m,n)=(2,1)$.

For each larger $k$, since $1$ is always a factor, then any positive $c \equiv -1 \pmod{k}$ works by choosing $u = 1$ and $v = c^2 + k$. For $k = 2$, using the odd factors $u$ and $v$ of $c^2 + 2$ for any odd $c$ comprise all of the solutions while, for $k \gt 2$, there are also many other $c$, $u$ and $v$ which work, especially for smaller $k$ values.

Also, for any $k$ where there's a solution of $c$ with $k \gt 2c + 1$, then there's also at least one $c_1 \gt c$ and $0 \lt k_1 \lt k$ where $c^2 + k = c_1^2 + k_1$ (at times also including the OP's result of $k_1 = 1$), so some solutions may be repeated.

Comment: This is nice, but I wouldn't say this is a complete answer, because it begs the question, how do you find values $u,v,c,k$ with $c^2+k=uv,$ $k\mid u+c, k\mid v+c.$ You need a factorization of $c^2+k$ such that $u,v\equiv -c\pmod k.$

Comment: On the other hand, it gives at least some other answers from the OPs. When $k=2$ and $c$ is odd, any factorization $uv=c^2+2$ is a solution. So the first such solution is $(c,k,u,v)=(1,2,3,1),$ giving $(m,n)=(2,1).$

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Thanks for the feedback. I also agree it's not a complete answer, but I just wanted to show there was a more general solution available, which included the OP's one as a special case. Nonetheless, I've now added some more details to my answer, including about $k = 2$ always working for any odd $c$, as you mentioned, as well as there being infinitely many solutions for any $k \gt 1$ by choosing $c \equiv -1 \pmod{k}$.

Answer (score 4):

Just a start.

Given any solution, let $c=\gcd(m,n).$

Then $m=cm_0,n=cn_0$ with $\gcd(m_0,n_0)=1.$

Now, $m_0\mid n_0(cn_0+1)$ and $n_0\mid m_0(cm_0+1).$ Since $\gcd(m_0,n_0)=1,$ this means:

$$m_0\mid cn_0+1, n_0\mid cm_0+1.\tag1$$

From this alone, we deduce $n_0,m_0,c$ are pairwise relatively prime. And from $c,m_0,n_0$ satisfying $(1)$ alone, we can deduce $m=cm_0,n=cn_0$ is a solution to your question.

To get your result, we need to deduce from $(1)$ that $(m_0-c)(n_0-c)=c^2+1,$ or $$m_0n_0-c(m_0+n_0)=1.$$

Don't see where to go from there.

---

**Further, less definitive ideas**

From $(1)$ we deduce that $m_0n_0\mid cn_0^2+n_0$ and $m_0n_0\mid cm_0^2+m_0.$ So:

$$m_0n_0\mid (n_0^2-m_0^2)c+(m_0-n_0)$$

But $m_0,n_0$ are both relatively prime to $m_0-n_0,$ so this means, if $m_0\neq n_0:$

$$m_0n_0\mid (m_0+n_0)c+1.$$

Answer (score 1):

$\frac{m}{(n,m)}$ divides $(n+1)$

$\frac{n}{(n,m)}$ divides $(m+1)$

$\frac{n}{(n,m)} \ell_1 = (m+1) \implies \frac{n}{(n,m)} \ell_1 = \frac{(n+1)(n,m)}{\ell_2}+1 \implies n_1 \ell_1 = \frac{(n_1 n_2+1)n_2}{\ell_2}+1 \implies n_1 = \frac{\left(n_2+\ell_2\right)}{\ell_1 \ell_2-n_2^2}$

where $(\ell_2,n_2) = 1$.

Any $n_2$ for which we can find $\ell_1,\ell_2$ with $(\ell_2,n_2) = 1$ such that $$n_1 = \frac{\left(n_2+\ell_2\right)}{\ell_1 \ell_2-n_2^2}$$ is an integer gives a solution by setting:
$$n = n_1n_2$$
$$m = \frac{(n+1)n_2}{\ell_2}$$

Hence $(\ell_1,n_2) = 1$.

Let, $$k = \ell_1 \ell_2-n_2^2$$
This gives,
$$n_1 = \frac{\left(n_2+\ell_2\right)}{k}$$
Assume $\ell_1$ chosen such that $k$ divides $n_2+\ell_2$.

Let $c = n_2$, then Solution is:
$$n = n_1 n_2 = \frac{c(c+\ell_2)}{k}$$
$$m = \frac{(n+1)c}{\ell_2}$$

where $$k  = \ell_1 \ell_2 - c^2$$
and $$k \ divides \ c+\ell_2$$

Hence fix $c,k$, if we can choose $\ell_1,\ell_2$ such that
$$k  = \ell_1 \ell_2 - c^2$$
$$k \ divides \ c+\ell_2$$

then we get a solution.

Coming to the Question, Choose $$u = \ell_1$$, $$v=\ell_2$$ and $k>1$ to get a new family of solutions.

This idea to reparamerterize my equations interms of $k = \ell_1 \ell_2 - c^2$ and $u = \ell_1$, $v = \ell_2$ is inpspired by answer from John Omielan.

An example, new family of solutions:
$$m = c$$
$$n = \frac{c(c+1)}{r}$$.

where $r$ divides $c+1$.